# iOS 7: Delete application with grey background

Tags: ios, itunes

I have problem with deletion of application with grey background:

[image]

Longpress at app, selecting X mark and "Delete" option do nothing. Also have tried to do it through iTunes with no result. But I can remove all other applications on device. Can someone help me with it?
I'm using iPad mini with iOS 7.0.3.

**UPDATE 1:**

I incorrectly edited plist that goes with .ipa file and tryed to install this .ipa. That's why this situation occured.

Comment: Have you tried to restart it?

Comment: Yes, I have. With no result again :(

Comment: Do you have an active and working wifi connection? For me connecting to the internet solved to problem, because I only got the "Could not install ..." dialog after that.

Comment: @PhilippOtto, yes, I have. Application completely downloaded, but looks like application installed incorrectly

Comment: You can try to delete the app through iTunes or via Xcode's Organizer (select the device > applications > check the app > delete)

Comment: @Alladinian, XCode's organizer don't see this application, and iTunes cannot remove ("X" mark do not appear at left top corner)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue with the plist, and push the app to the phone again. I've seen this issue with an invalid IPA, and I can't get around it until I update the app. But once I do, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: Now I have fixed this issue with plist, and installed application correctly. But this greyed app remained, i.e. I have both correctly installed app and this app with grey background

Comment: Did the app id change?

Comment: Now I cannot remember what exactly was wrong with that plist. Either download url for ipa or bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are signing the app with your "Ad-Hoc" provisioning profile BOTH when you Archive it, AND when you validate and distribute it from Organizer.

Comment: I don't have any problems with installing and distributing application. Now I cannot kick off aftermath of my previous try - remove this app.